# NP-Complete Hard-on-Average Problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, cr.crypto-security, one-way-function, average-case-complexity

This question considers a special class of problems in [(NP,P-samplable)](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:N#nppsamp). The question is:

> Do there exists a problem $(L,\mu) \in \mbox{(NP,P-samplable)}$ such that:
>
> - $L$ is $\rm{NP}$-complete, and
> - $L$ is hard on instances sampled by $\mu$; That is, for any $\rm{BPP}$ algorithm $A$, any polynomial $p(\cdot)$, and any all sufficiently large $n$:
>   $\Pr_{x \leftarrow \mu(1^n)}[A(1^n,x) = \chi_L(x)] < 1/p(n)$. (Here, $\chi_L(\cdot)$ denotes the characteristic function of $L$.)

Your answer can be based on any reasonable assumption, like:

- $\rm{P} \ne \rm{NP}$;
- one-way functions (or permutations) exist;
- factoring is hard;
- etc.

Another question is based on the following quote from [On Basing One-Way Functions on NP-Hardness](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/p_aggm.html):

`More than two decades ago, Brassard ("Relativized Cryptography") observed that the inverting task associated with a one-way permutation cannot be NP-hard, unless NP = coNP.`

> Is my understanding correct: It is saying that, there does not exist polynomial-time-computable permutations whose inverting is **worst-case NP-hard** and *hard-on-average* (unless NP = coNP)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there exist some NP language L that's hard on the average on some distribution $\mu$, then by applying the standard reduction $f$ from L to 3SAT you get that 3SAT is hard on $f(\mu)$.

Your understanding is wrong. By saying that the inverting task  for a function f is NP hard, one means that there is a polynomial-time algorithm A such that A can solve 3SAT on every input given black-box access to an inverter I that inverts f on a non-negligible fraction of the inputs.

Comment: Thanks Boaz. I think I get it now. For self-reference, I'll summarize it here: The existence of any hard-on-average problem implies the existence of NPC hard-on-average problems. Moreover, since the inverter works correctly on a non-negligible fraction of the inputs, it is a heuristic (without efficiency constraints) as defined in [Bogdanov's lecture notes](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~adib/538/lec10.pdf).